# Tensorflow cannot find variables after values change?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I have a custom model built in tensorflow 2.5.0 and I'm trying to do a grid search over hyperparameter values. The model trains properly but it throws an error when I re-initialize the parameters in the grid search loop (it seems to be related to the tensorflow graph, but I don't know what the exact source of the problem is). Minimal reproducible example is included below for a simple linear regression model.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

class Model:
    
    def __init__(self, X, y):
        
        self.X = X
        self.y = y
        
    # initialize model weights
    def initialize_model(self, lr, optimizer):
    
        self.lr = lr
        initializer = tf.keras.initializers.glorot_normal()
        self.weights = tf.Variable(initializer(shape = (X.shape[1],)), 
                                   name = 'weights')
        self.optimizer = optimizer(lr = lr)
        
    # loss function
    def sq_error_loss(self):
        
        preds = tf.linalg.matvec(self.X, self.weights)
        sq_error = tf.math.reduce_sum((self.y - preds)**2)
        
        return sq_error
    
    # one epoch of training
    @tf.function
    def train_step(self):
        
        with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
            loss = self.sq_error_loss()
        grads = tape.gradient(loss, [self.weights])
        self.optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(grads, [self.weights]))
        
        return loss
    
    # train the model for some number of epochs
    def train(self, num_epochs = 10):
    
        for e in range(num_epochs):
            loss = self.train_step()
            
        print('Training finished.')
                
    # grid search over different values of the learning rate hyperparameter
    def grid_search(self, lrs):
        
        for lr in lrs:
            self.initialize_model(lr, tf.keras.optimizers.Adam)
            self.train()

X = tf.Variable(np.random.normal(size = (1000, 10)).astype('float32'))
y = tf.Variable(np.random.normal(size = 1000).astype('float32'))

model = Model(X, y)

lrs = [i*0.01 for i in range(1, 11)]

model.grid_search(lrs)
```

Which throws the following error:

```
FailedPreconditionError:  Could not find variable _AnonymousVar143. This could mean that the variable has been deleted. In TF1, it can also mean the variable is uninitialized. Debug info: container=localhost, status=Not found: Resource localhost/_AnonymousVar143/class tensorflow::Var does not exist.
     [[node Adam/Cast_2/ReadVariableOp (defined at <ipython-input-112-1e76ddb3815a>:34) ]] [Op:__inference_train_step_293348]

Function call stack:
train_step
```

The error is fixed when I remove the @tf.function decorator from the `train_step()` function, but ideally I would like to use tensorflow graph execution rather than eager execution as it provides a significant speed boost to my code.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Well ,this would happen because you've change the OPTIMIZER itself, rather than the Learning Rate of it. And that would lead to some problem in @tf.function.

so do not change lr of the optimizer by changing the entire optimizer, you can achieve that by using the following code:

```
optimzer.lr = lr
```

hope that will be helpful!